# How can I connect PVC to this cast iron shower drain line?

Tags: plumbing, cast-iron

This is for a shower drain line to run into that cast iron pipe.
I'm looking for ways I can get something to connect the PVC to originally it was threaded at that junction point but I tried to remove the old pipe that was in there and as you can see it wouldn't move so some of it's still stuck in there. Looks like the threads were bonded in there. Who knows, because I can't get it out, but should I get a one and three quarter inch pipe tap?

I can't find those; that's the problem because that's about the size that I need to run the threads in. The cast iron is good and solid all around. I am just looking at the best way to fix this without cutting out the cast iron. Thank you!

The before:
[image]

The after:

[image]

Comment: dont want to cut out the cast iron just get something to go int that hole by cutting some threads. also fixed the sentences thank you

Comment: I know you don't, but that's easier (and gives a better outcome) than what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hint: A tap doesn't help you without robust equipment to position and turn it. You may also find the metal so decayed as to not support re-tapping.

Comment: yeah i will have enough room in there to move it and the cast iron is solid perfect for threading thank you for letting me know those pitfalls then, so is threading it and cutting it my only options?

Comment: I wonder if a saddle exists for that geometry - it seems like most are for round pipes, not Ts. Could also look at tapping bolt holes to attach a gasketed flange with threads.

Comment: No clue if this would meet plumbing code, but could you weld a stub onto that?  Or possibly round the penetration and use something similar to an Oatey Twist-n-Set toilet flange?